# how access to a file concurrently to add/edit/delete the data?

Tags: python, file-handling, filewriter

I want to create a text file and add data to it, line by line. If a data line already exists in the file, it should be ignored. Otherwise, it should be appended to the file.

Comment: This sounds like you need to use a database instead of a flat file.  If you can give more specifics we can probably help better.

Comment: here I am not maintaining a database to handle data and only use  a flat file. I thought this task as a simple script in python but when implement this realized which is somewhat hard work to handle concurrent access by many users. meanwhile I am newbie in python, don't have much experience in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this,

```
def retrieveFileData():
    """Retrieve Location/Upstream data from files"""
    lines = set()
    for line in open(LOCATION_FILE):
        lines.add(line.strip())
    return lines

def add_line(line):
    """Add new entry to file"""
    f = open(LOCATION_FILE, 'a')
    lines = retrieveFileData()
    print lines
    if line not in lines:
        f.write(line + '\n')
        lines.add(line)
        f.close()
    else:
        print "entry already exists"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        line = raw_input("Enter line manually: ")
        add_line(line)
        if line == 'quit':
            break
```

Comment: When you adapted my code, you forgot to make sure the file got closed in the code path it gets opened in. You should either use a `with` statement, or move `f.close()` to the end of `add_line`

Answer (score 2):

You are almost certainly better to read the file and write a new changed version. In most circumstances it will be quicker, easier, less error-prone and more extensible.

Comment: Thanks Martin, can someone explain me through code example, it is better having use threads in python? this is network file and a large number of users access at the same time.

Comment: having multiple users WRITE to the same file is tricky and should generally be avoided. There are libs to all write to the end of the same file (see logging). But if you all changing the same file - think of a better solution

Comment: use some more appropriate data structure like transactional database instead of a file

Answer (score 1):

If your file isn't that big, you could just do something like this:

```
added = set()

def add_line(line):
    if line not in added:
        f = open('myfile.txt', 'a')
        f.write(line + '\n')
        added.add(line)
        f.close()
```

But this isn't a great idea if you have to worry about concurrency, large amounts of data being stored in the file, or basically anything other than something quick and one-off.

Comment: Ther is a error returned in output,called " if line not in set:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable "

Comment: @user30412 -- sorry about that, I meant to put `added` there, which is of type `set`. Should work now.